# Expo In-app-purchase setup for Android is failing

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a react native project that uses In-app-purchases. On iOS, it works fine, but I recently started building for Android and the project fails to compile when I include expo's in-app-purchases module. I have set up in app products on the play store as [this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/) mentions as well as put   `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>` in my manifest file, however I feel like I am missing some other config step. Does anyone have any pointers? Here is some additional info

**Android sdk version** 32

**expo-in-app-purchases:** ^13.1.0

stack trace snippet:

```
/Users/uname/workspace/myproj/mobile/myproj/node_modules/expo-in-app-purchases/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/inapppurchases/UpdateListener.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    ArrayList<Bundle> results = new ArrayList<>();
              ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class UpdateListener
Note: /Users/uname/workspace/myproj/mobile/myproj/node_modules/expo-in-app-purchases/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/inapppurchases/BillingManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
45 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-in-app-purchases:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 46s
349 actionable tasks: 338 executed, 11 up-to-date
/Users/uname/workspace/myproj/mobile/myproj/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Users/uname/workspace/myproj/mobile/myproj/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/uname/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/uname/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/Users/uname/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/spawnGradleAsync.ts:83:18)
    at assembleAsync (/Users/uname/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/spawnGradleAsync.ts:57:16)
    at actionAsync (/Users/uname/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/runAndroid.ts:143:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```